# Meaning 'の場として'

Tags: academic-japanese

Having problems understanding the title of this academic paper:

> 心理臨床家の語りの場としてのスーパーヴィジョン

I can break down some of the elements to be 心理臨床家(clinical psychologist), 語り(talk or words), and スーパーヴィジョン(supervision). I'm having problems with の場として, though. I know 場 is place, is the meaning of this something like "Supervision of the clinical psychologist's talk location"? That sounds way too awkward and literal so I know I'm missing something. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but 語り has a technical meaning in psychology rather than meaning a generic "talk" (http://www.katariba.net/ , http://eprints.lib.hokudai.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2115/28908/1/90_P43-69.pdf ) .

Comment: I would infer 語りば seems to be the place where a counseling session takes place.  This gives me a guess as to what the entire title means but I don't really know the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word 'supervision' is actually treated as a place. The phrase literally means "supervision as a place of 語り of clinical psychologists".

> - 憩いの場としての家庭 home as a place of relief
> - 働く場としての大学 a university as a place of work

I feel 語り is something deeper than simple 'talk'. Probably 'storytelling' or 'narrative' is closer, but there may be a formal technical term for it.